# Should we unprocess [python-textprocessing]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The current [python-textprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-textprocessing) tag has 136 questions on Stack Overflow.

We currently have tags for both [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) and [text-processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/text-processing) (1721 questions).

Does this tag really add any meaningful information that is not available in both tags, and what is so special about python to get its own text processing tag.

I feel that this tag is pretty useless. Should we remove it?

Comment: Not sure, waiting for the pun in your title.

Comment: *Is a snake using a keyboard just a [tag:python-textprocessing]?*

Comment: Is [python-textprocessing] useful? Snakes don't have fingers.

Comment: Morbid, but perhaps ***Should we constrict [python-textprocessing]?*** or ***Should we suffocate [python-textprocessing]?***. (A [python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(genus)) is a [constrictor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constriction).)

Comment: Should we unprocess [python-textprocessing]?

Comment: Well `python-textprocessing` won't attract experts in `textprocessing` who don't program python. Maybe all `textprocessing` should be paired with a language.

Comment: @KL-1 That is exactly why a question can have multiple tags. And you tag the question with both `python` and `textprocessing`. What is your ultimate goal? To make unique tags for every 5 tags? Eg. `python-numpy-array-sorting-optimiation`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I tend to agree it's unnecessary so I tweaked the tags on a handful of questions (to make sure they had some Python language related tag) and then merged [python-textprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-textprocessing) into [text-processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/text-processing).

Answer (score -14):

I don't think the tag is a good candidate for burnination.

The [criteria for burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination/324071#324071) are:

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

Yes, the tag clearly describes the contents of the questions to which it's applied. A quick look at the questions in this tag shows they're all about text processing with Python. It's even less ambiguous than the [text-processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/text-processing) tag.

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Yes, text processing in Python is on-topic.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

Yes, it describes that the question is about a specific category of functions in Python.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

Yes.

---

It's true that [python-textprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-textprocessing) is essentially a duplicate of [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) combined with [text-processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/text-processing). However, I'm sure there are Python experts out there who are good at the subset of skills which make up 'text processing' in Python (i.e. file i/o, string manipulation, character encoding, etc.).

While the number of questions is relatively low at the moment, I don't see any harm being caused by the tag.

I think it's best to leave well-enough alone.

Comment: Yes, burnination criteria seems to be not fulfilled. At least, if they are taken literally. But that "essentially a duplicate" property... It seems that this property alone should be sufficient for burnination. "However, I'm sure there are Python experts out there who are good at the subset of skills which make up 'text processing' in Python" - With `python-textprocessing` splitted into `python` and `text-processing` these experts will be **experts** in **both tags** `python` and `text-processing`. Seems to be win-win for me.

Comment: The presence of this tag suggests the fact that text-processing in Python is somehow done differently which is not true.

Comment: *"Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?"* - NO. The two tags `python` and `text-processing` give all the necessary information... *"I'm sure there are Python experts out there who are good at the subset of skills which make up 'text processing' in Python"* - they can make a custom filter of both tags together and even be notified of new questions in that "field"...